# How to make anchor link be shown not exactly on top of the page?

Tags: css, html

When I click on an anchor link (which is linked to the article-header), it appears exactly on top of the page. But because of sticky page-header, article-header can't be seen.

I'd like to 'move it' down, to be seen just below page-header.

Here is codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/wolnio/pen/weEPLm).
(On the sidebar you have to open link called "HERE HERE HERE" ;) )

html:

```
<body>
<div class="main-container">
<div class="box">
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1>
        MAIN HEADER
        </h1>
    </header>
    <main class="main-content">
        <article class="single-article" id="warstwy">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>Warstwy modelu ISO/OSI</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><strong>Warstwa fizyczna</strong></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="tcp">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>TCP</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="ip">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>IP</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="tcp_ip">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>TCP/IP</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="udp">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>UDP (User Datagram Protocol)</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales. Cras lectus lorem, venenatis sed nisi vitae, egestas dignissim nulla. Maecenas quis ornare quam. Suspendisse blandit leo non felis feugiat, sed porttitor eros luctus. Aliquam in magna est. Suspendisse commodo elit et leo tincidunt accumsan. Fusce convallis lacus lacus, a laoreet arcu condimentum id. Etiam dictum tortor molestie eros lobortis faucibus. Cras aliquam eu sem ut dignissim. Morbi mollis sit amet augue sed euismod. Ut id varius lacus, nec sollicitudin neque. Integer lobortis sapien in consequat hendrerit. Duis a lectus id odio blandit ultrices vitae sed leo.</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="adresy">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>Adresy IP</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>

                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="dns">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>DNS (Domain Name Service)</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="vpn">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>VPN (Virtual Private Network - Wirtualna Sieć Prywatna)</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="metody">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>Metody szyfrowania i zabezpieczania transmisji</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="gniazda">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>Gniazda</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="single-article" id="architektura">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>Architektura klient-serwer</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra dignissim mauris id fermentum. Duis diam elit, tristique eget hendrerit in, ornare in mauris. Ut tempor mattis est in blandit. Proin gravida facilisis lacus a laoreet. Morbi quis fermentum lorem. Donec interdum purus vitae orci blandit sollicitudin id non sapien. Mauris elementum, enim ut consequat blandit, felis nibh faucibus libero, sed ultrices tellus dui et elit. Aenean nec elit sit amet nulla commodo dapibus. Sed pretium metus eget metus aliquam, ac pretium urna sodales.</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy 2017 Konrad Wolniak All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
    <nav class="site-nav">
        <header class="nav-header">
            <h2>Spis treści</h2>
        </header>
        <section class="nav-menu">
            <a class="accordion-head"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>Interfejsy</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Kodowanie kanałowe</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Zwielokrotnienie pasma</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Koordynacja czasowa</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Interfejsy szeregowe i równoległe</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Interfejsy systemowe</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Interfejsy zewnętrzne</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Polling</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Przerwania</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Point-to-point</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <a class="accordion-head">Procesory<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>CISC</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>RISC</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Architektura procesora</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Pozostałe o procesorze</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Potokowość</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Superskalarność</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Wielordzeniowość</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <a class="accordion-head">Procesy i wątki<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>PCB</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Stan i kolejki procesów</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Przełączanie kontekstów</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Synchronizacja/związek procesów i wątków</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Mutex, semafor i sekcja krytyczna</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <a class="accordion-head">Przechowywanie danych<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Budowa dysku</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Najważniejsze parametry</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Adresowanie</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Technologie dysków SSD</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Buforowanie zapisu</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>RAID</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Struktura logiczna dysku</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>MBR</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Systemy plików</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>FAT</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>NTFS</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>EXT2/EXT4</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Użytkownicy i grupy</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Uprawnienia oraz atrybuty plików i katalogów</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Pliki ukryte i wykonywalne</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <a class="accordion-head">Grafika<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Pamięć obrazu/bufor ramki</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Reprezentacja pikseli</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>GPU-pipeline</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Shader</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>OpenGL</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Prymitywy geometryczne</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Reprezentacja obiektów</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <a class="accordion-head">Linux<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Dowiązania do plików</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Systemy plików</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Ważne katalogi</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <a class="accordion-head">HERE HERE HERE<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#warstwy"><li>Warstwy modelu ISO/OSI</li></a>
                    <a href="#tcp"><li>TCP</li></a>
                    <a href="#ip"><li>IP</li></a>
                    <a href="#tcp_ip"><li>TCP/IP</li></a>
                    <a href="#udp"><li>UDP</li></a>
                    <a href="#adresy"><li>Adresy IP</li></a>
                    <a href="#dns"><li>DNS</li></a>
                    <a href="#hub"><li>Hub, switch, router</li></a>
                    <a href="#vpn"><li>VPN</li></a>
                    <a href="#metody"><li>Metody szyfrowania i zabezpieczania transmisji</li></a>
                    <a href="#gniazda"><li>Gniazda</li></a>
                    <a href="#architektura"><li>Architektura klient-serwer</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- <button class="hamburger">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </button> -->
    </nav>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same problem by adding `id` attribute somewhere on some hidden element, before your heading tag. In your case it would be something like:

```
<div id="tcp" style="margin-top: -100px; position: absolute;"></div>
<article class="single-article">
            <header class="article-title">
                <h1>TCP</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="article-content">
                <ul>
                    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) this is what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, you can't use anchors anymore. Try jquery animate scroll to top offset from top. Here is an example

```
    var $stickyNav = $('#nav_main'),
        stickyNavHeight = $stickyNav.innerHeight(),
        topPaddingOffset = 20,
        fullTopOffset = stickyNavHeight + topPaddingOffset
```

//on click of url

```
$('YOUR LINK').on('click', function(e) {

            var targetDiv = $(this).attr('href');      
      $('html, body').animate({

                    scrollTop: $(targetDiv).offset().top - fullTopOffset

                   }, 500);
});
```